# Determining the grids cut by a plane,formed from 3 vertices

Tags: c#, c++, geometry, computational-geometry

I found out an equation of a plane,from three vertices.
Now,if I have a bounding box(i.e. a large cube),How can I determine the grid positions(small cubes),where the plane cuts the large cube.

I am currently following this approach:

For each small cube center, say(Xp, Yp, Zp), calculate perpendicular distance to the plane i.e., (a*Xp + b*Yp + c*Zp + d)/ (SquareRoot Of (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)). This should be less than or equal to (length of smallCube * SquareRoot(3))/2.
If this criteria,gets satisfied,then I assume my plane to cut the large cube at this small cube position.

a,b,c,d are coefficients of the plane,of the form ax+by+cz+d = 0.

I would be really glad,if someone can let me know,if I am doing something wrong (or) also,any other simple approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to get a list of small cubes (grid voxels) intersected by given plane.

The simplest approach:

Find intersection of the plane with any cube edge. For example, intersection with vertical edge of AAB (X0,Z0 are constant) might be calculated by solving this equation for unknown Y:

```
aX0 + bY + c*Z0 + d = 0
```

and checking that Y is in cube range. Get small cube coordinates `(0, ky=Floor(Y/VoxelSize), 0)`  and then check neighbor voxels in order (account for plane coefficients to check only real candidates).

```
candidates:
0,ky,0
1,ky,0
0,ky-1,0
0,ky+1,0
0,ky,1
```

There are more advanced methods to generate voxel sequence for ray case (both 2d and 3d) like Amanatides/Woo algorithm. Perhaps something similar exists also for plane voxelization

Here is AABB-plane intersection test code from [this page](https://gdbooks.gitbooks.io/3dcollisions/content/Chapter2/static_aabb_plane.html) (contains some explanations)

```
// Test if AABB b intersects plane p
int TestAABBPlane(AABB b, Plane p) {
    // Convert AABB to center-extents representation
    Point c = (b.max + b.min) * 0.5f; // Compute AABB center
    Point e = b.max - c; // Compute positive extents

    // Compute the projection interval radius of b onto L(t) = b.c + t * p.n
    float r = e[0]*Abs(p.n[0]) + e[1]*Abs(p.n[1]) + e[2]*Abs(p.n[2]);

    // Compute distance of box center from plane
    float s = Dot(p.n, c) - p.d;

    // Intersection occurs when distance s falls within [-r,+r] interval
    return Abs(s) <= r;
}
```

Note that `e` and `r` remain the same for all cubes, so calculate them once and use later.

Comment: could zou please go through my algorithm once and explain me the changes ,I can do to make it working.Thanks

Comment: Emm... What is your algorithm? Your checking is not right  - it can produce false positive results. And I gave you a clue - how to get rid of brute force checking all small cubes.

Comment: I would be really glad,if you can slightly modify my check.Because,being a beginner in programmer,I am finding it a bit difficult to code the algorithm,you described.

Comment: But you have the same Google, haven't you? ;) Intersection test code added

Comment: Hi, in your algorithm, if my plane is in the form ax+by+cz+d = 0, are the values  p.n[0] `= a , p.n[1] `= b , p.n[2] `= b ,respectively?? could you please explain a bit on this

Comment: Also,in your described algorithm, point e evaluates to same every time.Because, b.max = c+(voxelsize/2) and b.max - c =  (voxelsize/2).So,irrespective of the grid,point e evaluates to the same value everytime.

Comment: Yes, p.n[0]=a and so on. And yes, you find both **e** and **r** once and use them instantly for all cubes